# Javascript Pacman Style Game Random map generator showing undefined properties

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to build a random map generator and in writing the function seems to work but the first column where I want to be walls starts showing undefined and random generated squares, and this affects the last column too. Is there something I'm missing?

```
var world = [];
var worldDict = {
    0: 'wall',
    1: 'blank',
    2: 'sushi',
    3: 'onigiri'
}

function drawWorld(){
    output = "";
    var worldheight = 15;
    var worldwidth = 15;
    for(var row = 0; row < worldheight; row++){
        world.push([row])
        output += "<div class = 'row'>"
            for (var x = 0; x < worldwidth; x++){
                //first row is all walls
                if(row == 0 || row == 14 || x==0 || x==14){
                    output += "<div class = '" + worldDict[world[row][x]] +"'></div>";
                    world[row].push(0);
                }else{
                output += "<div class = '" + worldDict[world[row][x]] +"'></div>";
                world[row].push(Math.floor(Math.random()*4));
                }
            }

            output += "</div>"
    }
    document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
}
drawWorld();
```

Comment: I would use canvas to make video games, instead... and use `const someVar = document.createElement(tagnameHere)` instead of `.innerHTML`, that way you can assign Events right to the variable before it's added to the DOM. Just advice.

Comment: great advice but this is for an assignment of mine so I don't get to choose my engine :)

Comment: It looks like your code is identical for the 4 `if/else if` branches - why not combine them into a single `if` statement separated by `||`?

Comment: Done I'll edit that on stack overflow as well sal, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the code a bit, this is what I came up with:

```
var world = [];
var worldDict = {
    0: 'wall',
    1: 'blank',
    2: 'sushi',
    3: 'onigiri'
}

function drawWorld(){
    output = "";
    var worldheight = 15;
    var worldwidth = 15;
    for(var row = 0; row < worldheight; row++){
        world.push([])
        output += "<div class = 'row'>"

            for (var col = 0; col < worldwidth; col++){
                //first row is all walls
                if(row == 0 || row == 14 || col==0 || col==14){
                    output += "<div class = '" + worldDict[0] +"'> </div>";
                    world[row].push(0);
                }else{
                  world[row].push(Math.floor(Math.random()*4));
                  output += "<div class = '" + worldDict[world[row][col]] +"'></div>";
                }
            }


        output += "</div>"
    }
    document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
}
drawWorld();
```

Changes made:

- moved the line `world[row].push(Math.floor(Math.random()*4));` before adding the `div` to the `output` variable
- removed `row` from `world.push([])` inside of the first `for` loop, it didn't make much sense why that was there, as that caused your matrix to be a `15x16` instead of `15x15` because you added the row number in the beginning (which may have accounted for the `undefined` you were getting)
- changed `worldDict[world[row][col]]` to `worldDict[0]` for the `if` condition, as it is always a wall so keeping it set to 0 would make it much more readable
- changed variable `x` to `col` so that it's more apparent what that variable is being used for. While this doesn't affect the functionality of your code, it makes it more readable

Here is a jsfiddle with this implemented (and slightly modified to show the outputs clearly): https://jsfiddle.net/rknzms3q/73/

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing the code. I am not sure if this is the output you are looking for.

```js
var world = [];
var worldDict = {
    0: 'wall',
    1: 'blank',
    2: 'sushi',
    3: 'onigiri'
}

function drawWorld(){
  output = "";
  var worldheight = 15;
  var worldwidth = 15;
  for(var row = 0; row < worldheight; row++){
    world.push([row])
    output += "<div class = 'row'>"
    
    for (var column = 0; column < worldwidth; column++) {          
      if(row == 0 || column == 0 || row == 14 || column == 14) {
        world[row].push(0);
        output += "<div class = '" + worldDict[0] +"'></div>";
      }
      else {
        world[row].push(Math.floor(Math.random()*4));
        output += "<div class = '" + worldDict[world[row][column]] +"'></div>";
      }
   }

   output += "</div>"
  }
  
  document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
}


drawWorld();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

.row {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wall, .blank, .sushi, .onigiri {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blank {
  background-color: black;
}

.sushi, .onigiri {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="world"> </div>
</div>
```